Global Flood Database v1 unmask 'jrc_perm_water'
I am using Google Earth Engine to generate mean area flooded in electoral districts of India.
What is a good way to remove the values of permanent water from the 'flooded' band and generate aggregate statistics of floods by region?
The following code only exported aggregate statistics by district for the bands in the original data such as "flooded", "duration". It doesn't export the following variables - "fl_predelim", "water_predelim", and "date".
// 1. Import data
var gfd = ee.ImageCollection('GLOBAL_FLOOD_DB/MODIS_EVENTS/V1');


//  2. select floods images that include India
var country="India";

var floods_india = ee.ImageCollection(
gfd.filterMetadata('dfo_country', 'equals',country));
 
var floods_india_sample=floods_india.filterDate('2008-01-01', '2013-12-31');
print(floods_india_sample,"sample");

//  3. import shapefiles
var boundary_predelim = 
ee.FeatureCollection('users/Tarana_Chauhan_files/india/AC_predelim');

// 4. isolate flood area from permanent water 
var meanflood_predelim=ee.ImageCollection(floods_india_sample).map(function(image){        
var date= ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var perm_water=image.select('jrc_perm_water');
var imgMasked = image.updateMask(perm_water);
var fl_predelim = imgMasked.reduceRegions({
collection: boundary_predelim,
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 250, // MODIS has a resolution of 250 m

});
var water_predelim = image.reduceRegions({
collection: boundary_predelim,
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 250, // MODIS has a resolution of 250 m

});
return image.set("stats",fl_predelim,water_predelim,date);
}).flatten();

Link to code:https://code.earthengine.google.com/6f256b6d59ec5b0e0094e58a75c712b0

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new use, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions here require the code (not just a link thereto) and a problem statement. "Did not work" is not a clear description of the problem.
